# ifstream not reading file for no obvious reason

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I wrote a very simple program for my class and, although it compiles without problems, I get no output on cout.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream fl("data.txt");    
    string s;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        fl>>s;
        cout<<s;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`data.txt` is in the same folder as `main.cpp`.

Comment: Is the file empty? Try adding `std::cout << std::endl` at the end to flush the output.

Comment: it is "not obvious" because you don't check if the file was opened.

Comment: in general when things can fail you should assume that they do fail.

Comment: `if(fl) { /* open succeeded */ } else { std::cerr << std::strerror(errno); }`

Answer (score 3):

> `data.txt` is in the same folder as `main.cpp`

... which is not necessarily the same directory you're in when you *run* the program.

Depending on the IDE, you may be in the binary directory, release directory, debug directory, or any one of a hundred different places :-)

You can generally find out where by simply doing something like one of:

```
system("pwd")
system("cd")
system("cmd /c cd")
```

in your code then seeing what it outputs. I'm not sure off the top of my head whether `cd` on its own will work since it may be an internal `cmd` command.

Then you'll either have to make sure the data file is *in* that place, or use a path name to it that will find it correctly. I tend to run my executables from the command line even when building within an IDE, just so I can ensure I'm in the right place.

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried using a file path before but it didn't work. The problem turned out to be pretty silly - I copied the path directly from Windows Explorer and didn't replace "\" characters with "/". It works now.

Answer (score 1):

There's no rule in C++ that says a file should be in the same folder as the file containing the code that reads it.

Almost certainly the file is not being opened because it's not in the correct location. You can test that with this code

```
ifstream fl("data.txt"); 
if (!fl.is_open())
    cout << "failed to open file\n";
```

Always check that a file open succeeds.